# What does boost::asio::spawn do?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-coroutine

I am unable to form a mental picture of how the control flow happens with spawn.

1. When I call `spawn(io_service, my_coroutine)`, does it add a new handler to the `io_service` queue that wraps a call to the `my_coroutine`?
2. When inside the coroutine I call an async function passing it my `yield_context`, does it suspend the coroutine until the async operation completes?

   ```
   void my_coroutine(yield_context yield)
   {
     ...
     async_foo(params ..., yield);
     ...   // control comes here only once the async_foo operation completes
   }
   ```

What I don't understand is how we avoid waits. Say if `my_coroutine` serves a TCP connection, how are other instances of `my_coroutine` invoked while on particular instance is suspended, waiting for `async_foo` to complete?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In short:

1. When [`spawn()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/spawn.html) is invoked, Boost.Asio performs some setup work and then will use a [`strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) to [`dispatch()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/dispatch.html) an internal handler that creates a coroutine using the user provided function as an entry point.  Under certain conditions, the internal handler can be will be invoked within the call to `spawn()`, and other times it will be posted to the `io_service` for deferred invocation.
2. The coroutine is suspended until either the operation completes and the completion handler is invoked, the `io_service` is destroyed, or Boost.Asio detects that the coroutine has been suspended with no way to resume it, at which point Boost.Asio will destroy the coroutine.

---

As mentioned above, when `spawn()` is invoked, Boost.Asio performs some setup work and then will use a `strand` to `dispatch()` an internal handler that creates a coroutine using the user provided function as an entry point.  When the `yield_context` object is passed as a handler to asynchronous operations, Boost.Asio will *yield* immediately after initiating the asynchronous operation with a completion handler that will copy results and *resume* the coroutine.  The previously mentioned strand is owned by the coroutine is used to guarantee the *yield* occurs before *resume*.  Lets consider a simple example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7008ac8a2054cb2f) `spawn()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>

boost::asio::io_service io_service;

void other_work()
{
  std::cout << "Other work" << std::endl;
}

void my_work(boost::asio::yield_context yield_context)
{
  // Add more work to the io_service.
  io_service.post(&other_work);

  // Wait on a timer within the coroutine.
  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_service);
  timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
  std::cout << "Start wait" << std::endl;
  timer.async_wait(yield_context);
  std::cout << "Woke up" << std::endl;    
}

int main ()
{
  boost::asio::spawn(io_service, &my_work);
  io_service.run();
}
```

The above example outputs:

```
Start wait
Other work
Woke up
```

Here is an attempt to illustrate the execution of the example. Paths in `|` indicate the active stack, `:` indicates the suspended stack, and arrows are used to indicate transfer of control:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::spawn(io_service, &my_work);
`-- dispatch a coroutine creator
    into the io_service.
io_service.run();
|-- invoke the coroutine creator
|   handler.
|   |-- create and jump into
|   |   into coroutine         ----> my_work()
:   :                                |-- post &other_work onto
:   :                                |   the io_service
:   :                                |-- create timer
:   :                                |-- set timer expiration
:   :                                |-- cout << "Start wait" << endl;
:   :                                |-- timer.async_wait(yield)
:   :                                |   |-- create error_code on stack
:   :                                |   |-- initiate async_wait operation,
:   :                                |   |   passing in completion handler that
:   :                                |   |   will resume the coroutine
|   `-- return                 <---- |   |-- yield
|-- io_service has work (the         :   :
|   &other_work and async_wait)      :   :
|-- invoke other_work()              :   :
|   `-- cout << "Other work"         :   :
|       << endl;                     :   :
|-- io_service still has work        :   :
|   (the async_wait operation)       :   :
|   ...async wait completes...       :   :
|-- invoke completion handler        :   :
|   |-- copies error_code            :   :
|   |   provided by service          :   :
|   |   into the one on the          :   :
|   |   coroutine stack              :   :
|   |-- resume                 ----> |   `-- return error code
:   :                                |-- cout << "Woke up." << endl;
:   :                                |-- exiting my_work block, timer is 
:   :                                |   destroyed.
|   `-- return                 <---- `-- coroutine done, yielding
`-- no outstanding work in 
    io_service, return.
```

Comment: What does the act of copying `yield_context` as it is passed to a coroutine do? If `foo` passes `yield` to `bar`, `bar` passed to `baz`, and `baz` calls `yield` - does the control go directly back to `foo`?

When the `timer.async_wait` call "yields", does the control go back to the coroutine-creator handler, which then returns?

When the time later expires, how does the control go back to `async_wait` - which then returns to `my_work`?

Comment: @CppNoob Boost.Asio's first-class support for Boost.Coroutine is a fairly thin facade.  Are you trying to understand how Boost.Asio uses Boost.Coroutine, or how Boost.Coroutine itself works?  Copying `yield_context` just creates another `yield_context` (not a coroutine).  When the `timer.async_wait()` yields the coroutine, control jumps to the left stack immediately after the point at which started the coroutine.  When `async_wait`'s completion handler is invoked, it resumes the coroutine, causing execution to jump to the right stack immediately after the point where it had yielded.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how Boost Asio uses coroutines - not from an implementation angle but as a control flow mechanism. I think of the yield_context as a conduit for relinquishing control to another context. In this example, the yield_context in my_work refers to the coroutine-creator handler context, and it is copied as the completion handler for async_wait. But when the completion handler of async_wait executes, the control goes back to my_work, not the coroutine-creator handler (which has exited by then). I clearly don't understand this, and I hope I could describe what's not clear.

Comment: @CppNoob The `yield_context` is used to represent the currently executing stackful coroutine.  In the above illustration, the coroutine is the stack on the right-side, and `yield_context` represents this within `my_work()`.  Coroutines allow suspending and resuming execution at certain locations, preserving local state on each context switch.  The coroutine suspends itself in `async_wait()`, and when the completion handler runs, it resumes the coroutine from the point at which it suspended.

Comment: @CppNoob When learning coroutines, I find that those who try to understand coroutines in terms of other constructs struggle when compared to those who approach it with a clean slate.  It may be worth considering going through the [Boost.Coroutine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html) documentation with a clean slate.  In particular, the Overview and Introduction may help explain coroutines, and the Motivation covers some great use cases, including a specific Boost.Asio example.

Comment: @TannerSansbury `"When the timer.async_wait() yields the coroutine, control jumps to the left stack immediately after the point at which started the coroutine. " ` during this step when control is on left,what is executing the body of async_wait???if service is ran in main,is there another thread in which body of async_wait is executed???if async_wait will be ran in main,would this prevent returning immediately to left after start,and the body of async_wait will be first executed in main then handler called then return to left"service run"???