# What is happend if a completion handler is neither invoked nor stored with C++20 coroutine?

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, coroutine, asio

## Overview

When I use BoostAsio's [CompletionToken](https://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/completion_tokens.html) facility, I design that `completion_handler` generated from `CompletionToken` finally invoked.

But I am interested in the behavior if `completion_handler` is neither invoked nor stored. In this case, `completion_handler` is simply destroyed.

I've tested the behavior with C++20 coroutine using `use_awaitable` CompletionToken. Then I observed interesting behavior. After `co_await` with `completion_handler` destroying path execution, the stack is unwinded and `ioc.run()` is finished in `int main()`. During this process, no exceptions are caught.
Is this expected behavior or undefined behavior? If it is expected behavior, where is the document? I couldn't find, so far.

### code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace as = boost::asio;


template <typename CompletionToken>
auto func(bool call, CompletionToken&& token) {
    auto init = 
        []
        (
            auto completion_handler,
            bool call
        ) {
            if (call) {
                std::move(completion_handler)();
            }
            else {
                // What is happend if completion_handler is neither invoked nor stored ?
            }
        };

    return as::async_initiate<
        CompletionToken,
        void()
    >(
        init,
        token,
        call
    );
}

struct trace {
    trace()  { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
    ~trace() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};

as::awaitable<void> proc1() {
    trace t; // destructed correctly
    try {
        {
            std::cout << "before call=true" << std::endl;
            co_await func(true, as::use_awaitable);
            std::cout << "after  call=true" << std::endl;
            
        }
        {
            std::cout << "before call=false" << std::endl;
            co_await func(false, as::use_awaitable);
            // the following part is never executed
            std::cout << "after  call=false" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "caught exception" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "co_return" << std::endl;
    co_return;
}

as::awaitable<void> proc2() {
    for (int i = 0; i != 2; ++i) {
        std::cout << "before proc1" << std::endl;
        co_await proc1();
        std::cout << "after  proc1" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    as::io_context ioc;
    as::co_spawn(ioc.get_executor(), proc2, as::detached);
    ioc.run();
    std::cout << "finish" << std::endl;
}
```

### output

```
before proc1
trace::trace()
before call=true
after  call=true
before call=false
trace::~trace()
finish
```

godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/3dzoYban6

### NOTE

In practice, I don't use "might uninvokable" token. I use an error code based approach.

```cpp
template <typename CompletionToken>
auto func(bool call, CompletionToken&& token) {
    auto init = 
        []
        (
            auto completion_handler,
            bool call
        ) {
            if (call) {
                std::move(completion_handler)(boost::system::error_code{});
            }
            else {
                // invoke with error code
                std::move(completion_handler)(
                    boost::system::errc::make_error_code(
                        boost::system::errc::operation_canceled 
                    )
                );
            }
        };

    return as::async_initiate<
        CompletionToken,
        void(boost::syste::error_code const&)
    >(
        init,
        token,
        call
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completion_handler type is

```
auto init = [](auto completion_handler, bool should_complete) {
    boost::asio::detail::awaitable_handler<boost::asio::any_io_executor> ch = std::move(completion_handler);
    if (should_complete) {
        std::move(ch)();
    } else {
        // What is happend if completion_handler is neither invoked nor stored ?
    }
};
```

`awaitable_handler` indirectly inherits from `awaitable_thread`, which on destruction indeed takes care of stack unwinding:

```
  // Clean up with a last ditch effort to ensure the thread is unwound within
  // the context of the executor.
  ~awaitable_thread()
  {
    if (bottom_of_stack_.valid())
    {
      // Coroutine "stack unwinding" must be performed through the executor.
      auto* bottom_frame = bottom_of_stack_.frame_;
      (post)(bottom_frame->u_.executor_,
          [a = std::move(bottom_of_stack_)]() mutable
          {
            (void)awaitable<awaitable_thread_entry_point, Executor>(
                std::move(a));
          });
    }
  }
```

Normally, the ownership gets transferred from handler to handler, but here, nothing references it anymore, so it ceases to exist.

Although this is implementation detail, it makes that if a coro can never be resumed, the reference count goes to zero. Also, along the way there is some decent code commenting that you may find insightful, e.g. `impl/awaitable.hpp` starts out with

```
// An awaitable_thread represents a thread-of-execution that is composed of one
// or more "stack frames", with each frame represented by an awaitable_frame.
// All execution occurs in the context of the awaitable_thread's executor. An
// awaitable_thread continues to "pump" the stack frames by repeatedly resuming
// the top stack frame until the stack is empty, or until ownership of the
// stack is transferred to another awaitable_thread object.
//
//                +------------------------------------+
//                | top_of_stack_                      |
//                |                                    V
// +--------------+---+                            +-----------------+
// |                  |                            |                 |
// | awaitable_thread |<---------------------------+ awaitable_frame |
// |                  |           attached_thread_ |                 |
// +--------------+---+           (Set only when   +---+-------------+
//                |               frames are being     |
//                |               actively pumped      | caller_
//                |               by a thread, and     |
//                |               then only for        V
//                |               the top frame.)  +-----------------+
//                |                                |                 |
//                |                                | awaitable_frame |
//                |                                |                 |
//                |                                +---+-------------+
//                |                                    |
//                |                                    | caller_
//                |                                    :
//                |                                    :
//                |                                    |
//                |                                    V
//                |                                +-----------------+
//                | bottom_of_stack_               |                 |
//                +------------------------------->| awaitable_frame |
//                                                 |                 |
//                                                 +-----------------+
```

### Docs?

I found the older answer where Tanner Sansbury explains the equivalent semantics for stackful coroutines [my emphasis]:

> The coroutine is suspended until either the operation completes and the completion handler is invoked, the io_service is destroyed, **or Boost.Asio detects that the coroutine has been suspended with no way to resume it**, at which point Boost.Asio will destroy the coroutine.

*From [What does boost::asio::spawn do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557582/what-does-boostasiospawn-do/30560228#30560228)*